# How to includeControllerXmlComments in Swagger .json files?

Tags: .net-core, swagger, swashbuckle, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

For my .net core 8.0 api project, I'm using `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 6.5.0` to `.AddSwaggerGen()` which generates and serves the a .json file at http://localhost:5229/swagger/my_api_name/swagger.json that I can browse at http://localhost:5229/swagger/index.html.

I want to inlcude the controller action `///<summary>` comment as a summary under the end point.

However, the only way that I can see in [the Swashbuckle Github repo](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore) is to include controller xmldocs is using

```cs
public static void IncludeXmlComments(
            this SwaggerGenOptions swaggerGenOptions,
            string filePath,
            bool includeControllerXmlComments = false)
```

I don't want to generate an XML file, how can I include the xmldoc comments in the .json file being generated?

Answer (score 1):

*I want to include the controller action `///<summary>` comment as a summary under the end point.*

This isn't possible without use of the Xml Document generated by the c# compiler.

[Get started with Swashbuckle and ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#xml-comments)

> Some Swagger features (for example, schemata of input parameters or
> HTTP methods and response codes from the respective attributes) work
> without the use of an XML documentation file. **For most features,
> namely method summaries and the descriptions of parameters and
> response codes, the use of an XML file is mandatory.**

From the above, You will have to use the  c# compiler to generate the xml documentation file (In order for `Swashbuckle` to pick up your endpoint descriptions in the `<summary>` element from the generated xml document) which is a painless process.

Simply enable [GenerateDocumentationFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props#generatedocumentationfile) in your `.csproj` and configure Swagger to read the generated file.